# Attempting to register WMI task results in Event ID 10 with Error 0x80041010

Tags: windows-10, wmi

I am currently trying to register a task in the WMI to run a script whenever a USB stick is inserted. For testing purposes I have written the following .mof-file (mostly taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27107902/permanent-wmi-event-consumer-doesnt-get-triggered-temporary-does)):

```
#PRAGMA NAMESPACE ("\\\\.\\root\\subscription")

instance of CommandLineEventConsumer as $Cons
{
    Name = "USB_Test";
    CommandLineTemplate = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe echo Hello, World! > testfile.txt";
    ExecutablePath = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe";
    WorkingDirectory = "C:\\Projects\\WMI";
};

instance of __EventFilter as $Filt
{
    EventNamespace = "\\root\\cimv2";
    Name = "USB_Test";
    Query = "SELECT * FROM __InstanceCreationEvent Within 5 "
            "Where TargetInstance Isa \"Win32_logicaldisk\" ";
    QueryLanguage = "WQL";
};

instance of __FilterToConsumerBinding
{ 
     Filter = $Filt;
     Consumer = $Cons;
};
```

Let's call this file `wmi.mof`. When I run `mofcomp.exe .\wmi.mof` the console output seems to indicate the process was successful. Using WMI Explorer I can also see the CommandLineEventConsumer, the __EventFilter and the __FilterToConsumerBinding. However I will also see the following entry in the Windows event log:

```
- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
    - <System>
          <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-WMI" Guid="{1edeee53-0afe-4609-b846-d8c0b2075b1f}" /> 
          <EventID>10</EventID> 
          <Version>2</Version> 
          <Level>2</Level> 
          <Task>0</Task> 
          <Opcode>0</Opcode> 
          <Keywords>0x8000000000000000</Keywords> 
          <TimeCreated SystemTime="2022-05-19T07:28:11.5064243Z" /> 
          <EventRecordID>108835</EventRecordID> 
          <Correlation ActivityID="{1a9c5853-650d-0006-43bb-9c1a0d65d801}" /> 
          <Execution ProcessID="7752" ThreadID="10424" /> 
          <Channel>Application</Channel> 
          <Computer>DESKTOP-GS3OHBK</Computer> 
          <Security UserID="S-1-5-18" /> 
      </System>
    - <UserData>
        - <data_0x8000003F xmlns="http://manifests.microsoft.com/win/2006/windows/WMI">
              <Query>//.//root/cimv2</Query> 
              <Namespace>SELECT * FROM __InstanceCreationEvent Within 5 Where TargetInstance Isa "Win32_logicaldisk"</Namespace> 
              <Error>0x80041010</Error> 
          </data_0x8000003F>
      </UserData>
  </Event>
```

One thing I immediately noticed is how `Query` and `Namespace` are switched in the event. They are the right way around in the .mof-file and also when I inspect the __EventFilter using WMI Explorer.

Attempting to trigger the event by inserting a USB stick does not yield any results. Neither the is the textfile.txt being created nor do I see any errors in the Windows event log. It's like the task exists in the WMI, but doesn't do anything.

This is my first time trying to use the WMI, so it's quite possible I've just made a beginner mistake somewhere. So far my googling regarding this issue has been unsuccessful, leading me to create this question here.

I am looking understand what causes the error, fix the error and get my WMI task to work.

edit: For context I have also tried to register a WMI task via a powershell script and it resulted in the same error. So I don't think it's an issue with my .mof-file, but rather with the WMI (?).

Comment: Unsure if this will help, but try updating your `CommandLineTemplate` by replacing `C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe` with just `/c` in front of `echo Hello, World!`.  Also, try removing the leading backslash in your `EventNamespace` to just `"root\\cimv2"`